# How to query the AWS CostExplorer API to get a specific tag's costs in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to set up some simple billing based on AWS usage so *thought* that I'd automate it by using AWS's [CostExplorer API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage) with the goal of querying the last months AWS bill by client_id and then creating the client invoice automatically based on the total value.

I've set up a tag on a number of AWS products I use for a specific client_id (Lambda, LightSail, SES, API Gateway and SQS).

Then created this simple example:

```
import os
import json

import boto3

region_name = os.getenv('region_name')
aws_access_key_id = os.getenv('aws_access_key_id')
aws_secret_access_key = os.getenv('aws_secret_access_key') or

client = boto3.client('ce',
                      region_name=region_name,
                      aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                      aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': '2021-01-01',
        'End': '2021-10-22'
    },
    Filter={
        'Tags': {
            'Key': 'client_id',
            'Values': ['1234567890'],
            'MatchOptions': ['EQUALS']
        }
    },
    Granularity='MONTHLY',
    Metrics=[
        'NormalizedUsageAmount',
    ]
)

print(json.dumps(response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

I got a result:

```
{
    "DimensionValueAttributes": [],
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "content-length": "1538",
            "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
            "date": "Thu, 21 Oct 2021 13:25:09 GMT",
            "x-amzn-requestid": ""
        },
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "RequestId": "",
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    },
    "ResultsByTime": [
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-02-01",
                "Start": "2021-01-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-03-01",
                "Start": "2021-02-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-04-01",
                "Start": "2021-03-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-05-01",
                "Start": "2021-04-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-06-01",
                "Start": "2021-05-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-07-01",
                "Start": "2021-06-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-08-01",
                "Start": "2021-07-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-09-01",
                "Start": "2021-08-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": false,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-10-01",
                "Start": "2021-09-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Estimated": true,
            "Groups": [],
            "TimePeriod": {
                "End": "2021-10-22",
                "Start": "2021-10-01"
            },
            "Total": {
                "NormalizedUsageAmount": {
                    "Amount": "0",
                    "Unit": "N/A"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But there are no costs even though there are definitely invoiced bills across this time period.  Is what I am trying to achieve not the use case for this or is there something trivial I have missed?

Comment: Did you enable this tag in the cost allocation tags?

Comment: Yes in Cost Explorer UI I can select the same period, select my tag and value and boom I see a graph.